# adding an item to the array causes Error in nextTick "RangeError"

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am learning VUE and I am trying to create a dynamic component to build navigation with children.

I have tried to create a new object with Object.assign and new array with Array, but always the same result.

here is part of my app related to this problem:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/mL48st20/
```

problem occurs in
CmsMenuItem.createChild() (on line 155)

```
    createChild: function () {

        // force expand list 
        this.isExpanded = true;
        console.log("Item add-child");

        --> this.data.childrens.push($BLANK_ITEM);
    },
```

Everything works just fine if I add a child to the existing item (loaded in Vue constructor) The problem occurs only when I try to add a child to a newly created item.

It pushes the new object to the item children array and also to its children array and so on.. infinite times, which explains the error.

Do you guys have any idea, how to solve this?

Thanks in advance for any bits of advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the same `$BLANK_ITEM` instance as a child of different items. You need to create new item instances each time.

Instead of:

```js
var $BLANK_ITEM = {
  name: $texts.newItem,
  url: '',
  languages: [],
  siteId: '',
  icon: '',
  target: '_self',
  title: '',
  childrens: []
};
```

you should have a function which creates a new item instance:

```js
function createBlankItem() {
  return {
    name: $texts.newItem,
    url: '',
    languages: [],
    siteId: '',
    icon: '',
    target: '_self',
    title: '',
    childrens: []
  };
}
```

then replace `$BLANK_ITEM` throughout your code with `createBlankItem()`, e.g.:

```js
methods: {
  addItem: function () {
    var item = createBlankItem();
    this.$emit('add-item', item);
    this.data.push(item);
  }
}
```

You also have some other errors related to the Sortable plugin, but I'm not sure what's going on there.